# MCP3461 analog side broken "somehow"?

Tags: adc, spi, teensy

I am trying to interface with an [MCP3461 ADC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP3461-2-4-Two-Four-Eight-Channel-153.6%20ksps-Low-Noise-16-Bit-Delta-Sigma-ADC-DS20006180B.pdf). I follow the SPI protocol described in the datasheet, and can read the output normally. I use the ADC in continuous conversion mode, 3.3V AVdd/DVdd/Vref and read the values using a [Teensy LC](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/teensyLC.html).

After I validated the operation, I tried connecting to an ATmega328P with an I2C LCD module for debugging purposes. The ATmega is also at 3.3V (supplied by the Teensy) and the SPI programmer is set to 3.3V logic level. It worked for a while and eventually "just stopped" working properly.

When I give commands to the ADC, the first command always returns a wrong status value, but all subsequent ones return the correct bits as expected. I put it into conversion mode and internal clock (like I have been doing), but it never returns "conversion ready" anymore, as if the whole analog side has stopped working. I can still read the registers normally and validate the values I'm writing in them.

I tried a second IC I had at hand, and got the same behavior. It started working just fine, and eventually stopped working as well.

I am confident that I have not violated any voltage levels and I'm using decoupling capacitors. There's clearly something I'm doing wrong that's frying(?) the ICs, but what could that be?

Comment: Schematic and board layout ?

Comment: Have you checked SPI speed, polarity, phase, and setup/hold times?

Comment: Connections are set up as shown on the datasheet. AVdd, DVdd, Vref+ go to 3.3V, AGND, DGND, Vref- go to ground. SPI signals go to their appropriate pins on the teensy LC board. ch0 and ch1 are connected to gnd and 3.3V and vice versa to check functionality.

Comment: @Justme I'm using the default settings, which worked right from the start. I found a third chip in my supplies and I'm testing this out again. The new IC works normally, the old one just returns 32767 when polled for a value, regardless of what I'm doing with ch0 and ch1 inputs.

Comment: What are the default settings for phase, polarity and speed then? And do they match to what the ADC chip requires?

Comment: About how long did it the parts last in the new configuration before the problem starts?

Comment: I went on to try specific settings to eliminate ambiguity. SPI clock of 1Mhz, MSB first, mode 0 (0,0) are used, and they do seem to work, only some times. The problem might be on some bad breadboard connection. but I have checked the presence of all the correct voltages on all pins. The digital connection has to be ok because I am getting responses as expected (and there is response scheme that makes it 100% obvious that it is the chip returning data and not random noise).

Comment: How is your reset/init sequence? Does the code make sure that CS is set high, before it is set low for first SPI command? Also, does it work if you remove the LCD usage if it worked without it? Can you post full schematics and code to see better?

Comment: I just spent several hours debugging a similar behavior. The chip's SPI interface still functions correctly but it also never finished a conversion. I later noticed that all register values (even reserved registers) were messed up from power on.  But they were constant, no noise. I believe that I somehow killed parts of the Chip (ESD?). A replacement chip works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to pinpoint the issue.
The chip has an IRQ pin that, by default, requires a pull up resistor or else the converter won't work properly. This can be solved by using a pull up resistor or setting the IRQ[1] bit in the IRQ register to 1: in that mode the pin does not require a pull up and will work without it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the IRQ Register bits [3:2], If bit 3 is HIGH (1) then data ready interrupts wont be updated on the status register (including the control bit)!!! So you want to ensure this bit is set LOW in order to receive the interrupt updates.

Bit 2 - will determine whether an external pullup is needed to DVdd on the IRQ/MDAT pin.

Please check your register values.

Comment: This wasn't the problem, it was already solved.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your setup might look something like this.  The cable capacitance depends on the gap of the conductor pair but is typically 25 to 35 pF/m and the rise time of the 1st pulse is determined by the pullup current.  Since this shared bus has asymmetric impedances 4k7 for hi and < 75 Ohms for low the fall time is much faster.

There are 2 sources of potential problems.

1. The added length to the LCD terminal may add too much capacitance for 4k7 pullup at the clock speed you are using.  Reduce the pullup R by adding 4k7 in parallel then 1k to see if there is any improvement.
2. if using SMPS for both devices and now sharing a common 0V gnd, there is a high probability that the RF leakage in the SMPS transformer which isolates DC is now injecting noise currents on your ground signal.  This can degrade the 1st bit as it switches from tristate to active state.  This may require an RF cap from AC gnd to DC gnd to suppress, if this is the case or STP cable and a detailed layout (photo) and signal capture on a DSO to analyze root cause.
3. Possible 3rd source is common mode noise coupling into the cable from the SMPS or line f that degrades the signal integrity to make it marginal on the 1st bit or byte.

Comment: The chip in question uses SPI, I'm not sure how this is applicable to my case.